# Can't capture HAR Request and Response using BrowserMob-Proxy(PhantomJS)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, har, browsermob-proxy

I am unable to capture request and response using browsermob(selenium+PhantomJS browser)

please refer the sample code

```
server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
server.start(0);
server.newHar("contracts");
```

Capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);  capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS,
     new String[] {"--web-security=false", "--ssl-protocol=any", 
                    "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes"});
capabilities.setCapability("takeScreenshot", true);
URL hubUrl = new URL("http://152.188.0.42:5555/wd/hub");
server.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
```

launching the application:

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubUrl,capabilities);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Creating the har file:

```
Har har = server.getHar();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("runnowNew.har");
har.writeTo(fos);
```

Har which is generated by using the above code:

```
{
  "log":
  {
     "version":"1.2",
     "creator":{"name":"BrowserMob Proxy","version":"2.1.2","comment":""},
     "pages":[{"id":"contracts","startedDateTime":"2016-10-05T12:56:33.460+05:30","title":"contracts","pageTimings":{"comment":""},"comment":""}],
     "entries":[],
     "comment":""
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the `PROXY` capability anywhere on the `capabilities` object? If not, PhantomJS won't know that it needs to use a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you don't use `BrowserMob Proxy` as a proxy for the Selenium traffic.
You need to set the proxy of Selenium (ip & port) to the one configured in `BrowserMob Proxy`.
IP is probably `127.0.0.1` since you work locally, and you can use `server.getPort()` to get the port that `BrowserMob Proxy` is listening to.